# Auto update textarea with text from text field

Tags: forms, text, textarea, field

Can i update a textarea field with custom text and text from a text field?
For example: 
i have a form with text field and textarea.. when i enter "Samsung" in text field, textarea field will show this: I want a Samsung phone. For LG will show I want a LG phone.
Is this posible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One very simple way using javascript :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function update(elem) { 
                document.getElementById('textareaDescription').value = " I want a " + elem.value + " phone";  
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Phone : <input type="text" onchange="update(this)">
        <br>
        Description : <textarea name="" id="textareaDescription" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Using the onchange event, the textarea will be updated once you lose focus (and changed!) the input.

Comment: You just saved my day! :) Thank you very much! But one more questions: how can i use two or more like this in the same page?

Comment: @CristianCrys just use a update function with more parameters, update(elem, elemtoupdate)

Comment: Hi, i just copied the same and it doesn't work for me:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raja777m/207q55sk/1/)
or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/207q55sk/2/)